# How to add css only for checkout page of rwd theme in Magento 1.9.0

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, checkout-page, styles

I need to add a custom css in `checkout.xml` file like this

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
    <reference name="head">

    <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>css/new.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

and its not working.
I have changed my theme like this [image]

I have created local.xml file at \app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\local.xml

I am thinking that local.xml file is not loading.

Comment: can you provide your checkout page URL, though its local URL, and If you are using custom checkout extension then also let me know

Comment: My URL: http://magento/checkout/onepage/

Comment: I tried your solution but not working yet

Comment: check updated answer

Answer (score -4, accepted):

> You can add this xml code in your local.xml it will add css only for
> cart page

create a local.xml file in

> app/design/frontend/theme/default/layout/local.xml
>
> Paste below code in local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <layout version="0.1.0">
      <checkout_cart_index> translate="label">
         <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <stylesheet>css/new.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
         </reference>
     </checkout_cart_index>
  </layout>
```

> OR

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <layout version="0.1.0">
      <checkout_cart_index> translate="label">
         <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/new.css</name>
            </action>
         </reference>
     </checkout_cart_index>
  </layout>
```

Comment: I dont see local.xml file in layout folder. Where can i find it?

Comment: Its not working

Comment: change : app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/local.xml

Comment: It must works. Please clear cache and reload the page, then take view-source of your page, then check the css file name

Comment: Which theme are you using? default theme rwd or any other custom theme?

Comment: I am using rwd and i have changed. Please look at the screenshot I have attached

Comment: yes i have added my local.xml file magento\app\design\frontend\rwd\newtheme\layout\local.xml

Comment: Ok i got my problem solved. Thank you. Actually Murtuza Zabuawala solved the other half of my problem.

Comment: @RitaJose I need to complain about your behaviour you have updated your code after my answer accepted, this should not be done https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/196995/revisions

Comment: @AbhilashNarayan,the above code  has mistake wrong code,But how it work for you??? it is strange

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala  i'm replaced current code to my previous answer

Comment: @RitaJose Just want to know why you have done that

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala and ritarose,Please  no more  word. Hope both of you understood the situation.Please carry good work at MSE

Comment: @AmitBera appreciate your efforts , thank you

Answer (score 8):

You are using the wrong handler

```
 <checkout_cart_index>
```

Will add css to cart page not in check out page

replace with

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
```

this will add content to checkout page

Comment: You are always welcome :)